# Pointer Address passed as argument seems to change in function call

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gtk, arguments

Well, it may be my last question befor being blocked from asking, but I just can't see what the problem is.

I am currently trying to pass a pointer to a struct as an argument, here is the structure.

```
typedef struct GTKObj
{
    GtkFileSelection *file_selector;
    double ***weightsInHid;
    double **weightsHidOut;
    double **trainingOutput;
} GTKObjStore;
```

In main.c, I have three arrays (named like the one in the struct) but since they are not dynamically allocated, I didn't find any way to fill the GTKBojStore's one without memcpy()

```
//main.c
GTKObjStore *gtkArg = malloc(sizeof(*gtkArg));
```

Then, I have to pass them in a GTK callback function, but when I try to access one of the element, I have a segfault. So I tried to print some addresses to see, and they never are the same.

```
//main.c
printf("gtkArg before passing it     :  %p\n", gtkArg);
printf("&gtkArg before passing it    :  %p\n", &gtkArg);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pButton),
        "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK(creer_file_selection), gtkArg); <<-- Here
```

and in the function, I print again:

```
void store_filename (GTKObjStore *testData)
{
    printf("Passing... gtkArg -> argument\n");
    printf("&argument not casted in struct :  %p\n", &testData);
    GTKObjStore *argument = testData;
    printf("argument      casted in struct :  %p\n", argument);
    printf("&argument     casted in struct :  %p\n", &argument);
    printf("%d - %d - %d -%f\n",i,j,k, argument->weightsInHid[0][0][0]); //<<--Segfault
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

I don't understand why the address changes, or maybe I am doing something stupidly wrong...
**Has anybody an idea ?**
Don't hesitate to ask for more code

Thank you

Comment: too much code. use a debugger to narrow down your problem.

Comment: Edited, left only what may cause error.
Better ?

Comment: What is the type of `gtkArg`? What is `sizeof(*gtkArg)`? What is `sizeof(GTKObjStore)`? And why are you shadowing the `argument` argument in `store_filename()`? Also, you can use `g_malloc0()` or `g_new0()` (provided by GLib, which GTK+ uses) to allocate and zero memory.

Comment: I put what the type of gtkArg was. It's a structure.
Why have I downvotes ? No explanations just downvotes. My questions doesn't seem stupid to me

Comment: It doesn't sound stupid to me either, but I'm trying to rule out potential sources of errors based on what you did provide. Last question for now (as I have to head out): is `argument->weightsInHid` NULL, or is `argument->weightsInHid[0]` NULL, or is `argument->weightsInHid[0][0]` NULL?

Comment: Thank you. Since argument is supposed to take testData, none of the weightsInHid should be NULL. But it doesn't take the right address, at least it doesn't look like so, so they are garbage. testData's arrays (function argument) are initialized and fill before passing in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please don't paste pictures of output. They are hard to cut/paste from. Show the output in *text* form.

Second, you have a preoccupation with addresses of pointers: `&gtkArg`, `&testData`, `&argument`, but they are all *irrelevant*.

What matters is the *value* of the argument being passed into `store_filename()`. It should be `0x21d1220`, but you are getting an unexpected value of `0x2328870` instead. The real question you should be asking is: *why* are you getting that value?

Now, you've registered `creer_file_selection()` as the callback. Presumably *it* receives correct value of the data, and then invokes `store_filename()` with incorrect value. But you never show the code for `creer_file_selection()` (or any function in between `creer_file_selection()` and `store_filename()`). The bug is likely in one of these intermediate functions.

The best way to debug this... is to use a debugger. Run your program under GDB until crash point, then use GDB `where` command, and observe which functions are called with which arguments. You should observe that the callback: `creer_file_selection()` is invoked with expected argument, but some function down the call chain is not. The caller of the function that is called with the wrong argument... is likely where the bug is.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your constructive answer, I'll check this as soon as I get home